# Using some beans in Filter bean class?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

In my filter bean class, I added some beans dependency (with `@Autowired` annotation). But in the method `doFilter()`, all my dependency beans have null ...

```
public class FacebookOAuth implements Filter
{
@Autowired
private BusinessLogger logger;

@Autowired
private IUserSessionInfo userSessionInfo;

@Autowired
private FacebookOAuthHelper oAuthHelper;

public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException
{
    // Nothing to do
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws   IOException, ServletException
{
    // HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)sr;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) sr1;

    String code = sr.getParameter("code");

    if (StringUtil.isNotBlankStr(code))
    {
        String authURL = this.oAuthHelper.getAuthURL(code);
```

**this.oAuthHelper** is equal at null (and other dependancy beans to) ...

Could you help me ?

---

In fact I don't use MVC notion on server side (Spring). For my side client I use Flex technology and BlazeDS servlet ton communicate with my server.

So, that is the reason, I use the Filter bean notion.

So, how can I handle my session bean notion in my Filter bean ?

---

Skaffman,

I implemented your idea, so I update my application.xml with :

```
<bean id="FacebookOAuthHandler" class="com.xx.FacebookOAuthHandler" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
       <prop key="/fbauth">FacebookOAuthHandler</prop>         
    </props>
   </property>
</bean>
```

and my **FacebookOAuthHandler** class :

```
public class FacebookOAuthHandler extends AbstractController
{
@Autowired
private BusinessLogger logger;

@Autowired
private IUserSessionInfo userSessionInfo;

@Autowired
private FacebookOAuthHelper oAuthHelper;

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // TODO

    return null;
}
```

But, this method **handleRequestInternal** is never called when my URL is : http://xx.xx.xx.xx/MyApp/fbauth

Comment: What does your spring configuration look like?

Answer (score 34):

I was facing the same problem and my first idea was to manually force Spring to apply @Autowired annotation to the filter like proposed here

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60983-Autowiring-the-servlet-filter

But I don't like the idea of hardcoding the bean name in my Java class.

I found an cleaner way that works as well:

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
            filterConfig.getServletContext());
}
```

Comment: The reference is dead. The whole forum was closed in 2019. Have you an active reference. please?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming this `Filter` is wired up in your `web.xml`, then this isn't going to work, since it's not managed by Spring, it's managed by the servlet container. So things like autowiring won't work.

If you want to define a servlet filter as Spring bean, then you need to define it in the webapp's root application context (using a `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml), and then [defining a `DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) which delegates to your Spring-managed bean to do the work.

However, do you really need a servlet filter for this? What what I know of Facebook auth stuff, this could be [done just as easily with a Spring `HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). This would be considerably less configuration work than a delegating filter.

Comment: Hi Skaffman ! Thanks a lot for your answer. Yeah, all my configuration files (web.xml, and my application.xml) are ok (with ContextLoaderListenner, with delegatingFilterProxy, etc.). But, even with this configuration, I can't used bean in my filter, that's right ?

Comment: Can you please give some code examples how to define a servlet filter as a spring bean?

Comment: I actually saw http://pro-programmers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/spring-bean-as-servlet-filter.html article, but I am not using SpringMCV. will it help?

Comment: The 1st paragraph is very interesting. The 2nd one  says nothing about how to define something using CLL, and nothing about how to define and how to delegate by DFP. The third paragraph has the same problems. How the HI can serve as a filter? How and where should it be registered? References given are useless - they are simple links to docs, that we could easily google ourselves by the name of the class. And there are no answer to any questions mentioned. So, the answer is rather empty.

Answer (score 7):

Look at this answer on site of spring: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60983-Autowiring-the-servlet-filter

In brief - you can manually force spring to apply @Autowire annotation to your filter:

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    ServletContext servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = 
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory =
           webApplicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

    autowireCapableBeanFactory.configureBean(this, BEAN_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it a now old question, but there is no example of usage of `DelegatingFilterProxy` in current responses, and one recent question asking for such an example was marked as a duplicate for this one.

So a `DelegatingFilterProxy` is a special filter that knows about root `ApplicationContext` and delegates its `doFilter`to a bean.

Example : `MyFilter` is a class implementing `Filter`, and myFilter is a spring bean

```
<bean id=myFilter class="org.example.MyFilter ...>...</bean>
```

or in a configuration class

```
@Bean
public MyFilter myFilter() {
    MyFilter myFilter = new MyFilter();
    //initialization ...
    return myFilter;
}
```

In web.xml, you just declare a `DelegatingFilterProxy` with same name as the bean :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That way, as `myBean` is a true bean, it can be injected normally with other beans with `@Autowired` annotations, and its `doFilter` method will be called by the `DelegatingFilterProxy`. As you can use spring init and destroy methods, by default `init` and `destroy` methods will not be called, unless you specify the "targetFilterLifecycle" filter init-param as "true".

Comment: I'm trying to do it in my project, but at server start, an error is thrown: Severe: Exception starting filter myFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myFilter' is defined. I've tried to configure through either XML and Annotation. It seems that web.xml is read before bean is configured.

Comment: I used it in many projects, and never had any problem. But the bean must be declared in root context, not in dispatcher-servlet one. You should show how you declare you bean.

Comment: I'm sorry for my rookiness, but how can I declare a bean either in root or dispatcher-servlet context? I have just created a configuration class in which I have put a "@Configuration" annotation, an then created a "@Bean" (refering to myFilter class).

Comment: @Alex Ok, so it should be in root context. Is the remaining of Spring configuration working correctly, an how is it declared ?

Comment: Yes, it is. My only trouble is on filter stuff. I don't know wether the package where configuration class is matters (I don't think so), but is there a kind of configuration in order to set it into root context?

Comment: @Alex : what matters is that the package is scanned ... in any doubt, put the configuration class in a package where you have other configuration classes that are correctly processed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62418/discussion-between-serge-ballesta-and-alex).

Comment: Yes, I did it. Actually, for test purposes, I put myFilter bean in the very class where I'm configuring sessionFactory (which is actually working fine). And it have not been configured. But note that this file seems to be processed after web.xml.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm behind a corporate firewall. I'm not able to chat.

Comment: I've achieved the answer (through an "experimental research"): my /resources/spring/application-config.xml was not properly configured. Tag <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany..."/> was not present in this file. Other beans was normally working probably due to their scope to be dispatcher-servlet. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting null pointer while accessing service class bean in filter class using Autowiring . I searched more than 100 links but not able to find solution.
I am using spring Boot Application and configuration which is required to get bean in filter class :

FilterConfig.java which provides application context Object.

```
@Component
public class FilterConfig  implements ApplicationContextAware{

private static ApplicationContext context;


public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
       return context;
    }
public  static <T> T getBean(String name,Class<T> aClass){
    return context.getBean(name,aClass);
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    context = ctx;
}   

 }
```

in Filter class , I used this like :

```
 UserService userService =FilterConfig.getBean("UserService", UserService.class);
```

UserService this is bean name which is mentioned in

```
  @Service("UserService")
  public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService { ...}
```

No Configuration in main class of spring Boot :SpringBootServletInitializer