# Spring container unable to inject bean in custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am facing an interesting issue. If you could enlighten me about this, I will appriciate.

Here's a scenerio; I am using Custom Filter in Spring context. I specified it as a DelegatingProxyFilter. So I made Spring context aware of this filter as a bean. I can use `@Autowired` annotation for `ApplicationContext` class and `TranslationUtils` class as you have seen bin the below code. But I can not use `@Autowired` with

```
CommonsMultiPartResolver(**org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver**).
```

Spring container can not inject it. If there is something that I have missed , Please let me know .

Code pieces     Here is my filter  :

```
@Component(value = "multipartExceptionHandlerFilter")
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {``
@Autowired // working !!
private TranslationUtils trans;

@Autowired // working !!!
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired // not working !!
@Qualifier("filterMultipartResolver") // also not working !!!
CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //do something
        }
    }
}
```

filter described in web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartExceptionHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartExceptionHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is bean definition :

```
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
      p:maxUploadSize="52428800" p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

So what could be the problem?

Comment: Please show your error log ouput.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartExceptionHandlerFilter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Comment: And also it stucks in loop with this error message.

Comment: On your filter you declare `multipartExceptionHendlerFilter` as `DelegatingFilterProxy` but on your java class it extends `OncePerRequestFilter`. This class implements `DelegatingFilterProxy`?

Comment: To make spring context aware of this filter as a bean.

Comment: Pelase refer :
 http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html
Please refer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645650/using-some-beans-in-filter-bean-class