# Spring @Autowire retuning null while creating an object

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, datasource

I am new to this Spring and trying to learn it.

I am using basic auth jersey and using spring to inject my db props and instantiate the class. However I am getting null pointer exception when I try this with a REST call using postman.

Below is code snippet

AppContx.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rest" />


<bean id="userDao" class="com.rest.dao.UserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
</bean>

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/Weber" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Filter

```
  @Provider
  public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

/*ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
IuserDao userDao = (IuserDao) ctx.getBean("userDao");*/

@Autowired 
UserDao userDao;

public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}
  if (userDao.getUSerForAuthentication(password, username) == 1) {
            String userRole = "ADMIN";
            if (rolesSet.contains(userRole)) {
                isAllowed = true;
            }
```

DAO

```
@Autowired 
private DataSource dataSource;


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

I am successfully able to inject DB properties to my data source using @Autowired but I am unable to instantiate the UserDao in my Filter class.

Thank You

Mark

Comment: I suggest, remove this from your code. <bean id="userDao" class="com.rest.dao.UserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
</bean> and add @Component to your UserDao class

Comment: Why you required getter & setter for userDao ? Can you please remove it and try again.

Comment: Hi Vinit yeah true we dont need them. But my conern was I am unable to create a new object of UserDao in my Filter class. Also removed getter and setter methods no luck. still I am getting NPE

Comment: I ran into this same issue when attempting to Autowire into a filter and into a HandlerInterceptor.  See this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645650/using-some-beans-in-filter-bean-class.  I implemented something similar and it works.